# Is it possible to change array's width in output pane of VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't prefer to print the text unnecessarily into multiple lines.
But in the VSCode output(terminal) pane, line-wrap(line-break) is automatically applied to arrays.
It's limited to 5 elements per line.
I want to see the output as red text.

like these
[image: like these]

(FYI, the extension in the image is Code Runner.)\

Comment: What is the code that you are trying right now? Also, instead of a linked image, could you please paste the text in the image into your question?

Comment: Below is the code I tried.

Comment: console.log('0000a0000b0000c0000d0000e0000f0000g');
console.log([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
console.log([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]);
console.log([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]);
console.log([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]);

Answer (score 0):

Simply use JSON.sringify().

example :

```js
const array = [2,3,2,23,3,3,5,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,4,2];
console.log(JSON.stringify(array);
```

Output :

```js
[2,3,2,23,3,3,5,2,3,4,2,3,4,3,4,2]
```